# How to use angular material md-grid-list

Tags: angularjs, pug, material-design, stylus

I am writing an application, which was scaffolded by the yeoman generator [ng-poly](https://github.com/dustinspecker/generator-ng-poly). I use sylus as an css pre-processor and jade as an template-engine. I want to use the md-grid-list and md-grid-tile directives of angular-material. So here is the code snipped for the template:

```
div.content(layout='row', layout-margin)
  md-grid-list(md-cols='5', md-row-height="4:3", md-gutter="1em")
   md-grid-tile(ng-repeat='box in dashboard.boxes')
     p I am a paragraph
```

The result is as followed:

[image: Result of the template]

I am using angularjs v1.3.14 and angular-material v0.8.1.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you forget to include one of the css files? Does it work if you link the (correct) raw css files instead of preprocessed ones?

Comment: I added `link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://material.angularjs.org/docs.css')` to my index.jade. Result stays the same.

Comment: Are you adding more css files - some that would override the styles intended from material?

Comment: I added the link to angulat-material at the end of the head of the index.jade - So that could not be the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue because of `layout="row"`.

I replaced it by `layout="column"` and it worked.

Did you try this?